# Unable to pass additional flags to gcc through mpicc

Tags: c, gcc, mpi, compiler-flags

I have a C program that uses OpenMPI libraries. I am also using functions from libm and have included `math.h` in my program. When compiling using `mpicc`, like so
`mpicc -lm program.c -o program.out`
compilation succeeds, but linking fails, with `ld` unable to link libm and the following three lines of error
`/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cct0O5Yv.o: undefined reference to symbol 'log10@@GLIBC_2.2.5'`
`/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

From what I understand, `mpicc` is just a wrapper for `gcc` whose job is to pass compilation and linking flags to `gcc`. Why is it not passing `-lm` to `gcc`? How do I make it pass additional flags to `gcc`? I couldn't fine anything in the man pages.

I used `--showme:compiler` and `--showme:linker` with `mpicc` and passed those flags to `gcc` along with `-lm`, and it generates the final executable just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the order of the command line arguments passed to `mpicc` matters. In order to make `mpicc` pass additional flags to `gcc`, place them before the source file

`mpicc -lm program.c -o program.out`

Flags placed after the source file will be treated as flags to the wrapper and not the "kernel" (in this case `gcc`).